# Efficiently apply R functions over multidimensional array

Tags: r

I have an array that is composed of a list of lists of lists of lists..
For instance say

```
data[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[5]]
```

returned a number.  Now I need to compute say the smallest of these numbers across

```
data[[1]][[a]][[b]][[c]][[5]]
```

Where

```
a = 1:10
b = 1:100
c = 1:100
```

I could certainly do this with some nested for loops, but I feel like an apply command with min, or something equivalent in dyplr, should handle this without issue.

Alright a *very rough* example would be, say,

```
test <- rep(list(rep(list(rep(list(rep(list(rep(1:5,5)),100)),100)),10)),14)
```

And that is then that:

```
test[[1]][[14]][[10]][[100]][[100]][[5]]
```

Returns the number 5.
I now want to say take the minimum over the dimensions, in theory thought of like this:

```
test[[1][[1:10]][[1:100]][[1:100]][[5]]
```

Now obviously what we are going to get by taking the minimum number that ever appears over these (10*100*100) values will be 5, because the only number itself is 5.

Comment: Can you please add some reproducible and minimal sample data using `dput`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with dput but I will certainly try to do so.  Thank you for the suggestion, I can understand this to be specific.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `pmin`. Like stated above, add some sample data.

Comment: You can also generate some mock-data that is representative of your actual data. That way we avoid ambiguities regarding the format of your actual data. Thanks

Comment: If your data is actually rectangular, put it in a real `array` class object instead of a list of lists of lists of lists. Then this will be a simple `apply` call.

Comment: So the data itself starts off as an array, made into a list of arrays, etc and I do have access to that.  Working backwards that way is certainly efficient as at that point i can just call min itself, or which.min for the indices it occurs at.  I was hoping something could traverse the lists just as efficiently.

Do you have any tips on turning my example posted directly into an array, without forming it as an array from the beginning?

Comment: I think you can go back to `array` using `reshape2`, first `melt` your list and then `acast` it to an array. Can't speak to the efficiency of that approach. There may be more modern options in `purrr`.